# InfluxDB "influx" command won't connect to CLI

Tags: docker, influxdb

I've got a docker instance of influxDB

```
docker run -d -p 8086:8086 -v influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb --name influxdb influxdb
```

Instead of being in the CLI where I can create databases and everything I get a help page with list of commands and usage from "Influx CLient" when running `docker exec -it influxdb influx`

How do I get into the proper CLI?
Web interface works btw

Cheers

Comment: apparently this is only an issue in influxdb v2.0. using version 1.8 I get to the CLI as expected

Comment: I see the same behavior in 2.0.7

Answer (score 1):

Go into docker shell:

```
docker exec -it influxdb bash
```

Try to run from within docker:

```
influx query 'from(bucket:"YOUR_BUCKET_NAME") |> range(start:-1m)'
```

You can also read some info:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/19986

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with

```
docker exec -it influxdb bin/bash
```

after that, you will enter the container you created before.

Then, you can use the command `influx` to connect the CLI.